# Instance Template using Machine Image

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have used AWS. I am new to GCP. I am really confused by the concept called Machine Image from GCP for some reason. It sounds a lot like AWS AMI.

I created a Machine Image from a running VM.

But interestingly when I create a new instance / instance template , I do NOT see any option to choose the `machine image`.

[image]

How to create an instance template which uses the machine image?

Comment: Are you trying to use a Machine Image from existing, running VM instance(s)? If this is the case, you may create the Machine images first before you can use them as a Boot Disk for your Instance Template. You may refer to this documentation for Creating Machine Images: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates

Comment: I have a machine image created from a running VM. The question is - why I am unable to use it for a launching new VM or Instance Template.

Comment: It appears that using Machine images in Instance templates are not supported per document: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images. Instead, you may create a custom image based on the running VM and use it as your source image when creating the Instance Template. You may refer to this documentation for reference: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#based-on-existing-instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Custom images](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/compute-engine-gets-machine-images) capture the contents of a single disk, for example, a boot disk, which can be used to create new instances that are preconfigured with the apps that you need, so that you don’t have to configure public images from scratch.

[Machine images](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/compute-engine-gets-machine-images) are a more comprehensive resource that can contain multiple disks, as well as all of the information required to capture and create a new instance, including:

- Instance properties (machine type, labels, volume mapping, network tags)
- Data of all attached disks (one or multiple)
- Instance metadata
- Permissions, including the service account used to create the instance

Please see this documentation on [when its best to use machine image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images#when-to-use)

For your use case, instead of using a machine image, you may just create a `Custom Image` off of your running instance and use it as a Boot Disk (Custom Image) for your Instance Template. You may refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#based-on-existing-instance) as a guide.

Comment: In addition to this answer, I recommend shutting down the instance before creating an image.